# How to convert a datetime string to date and add +4 hours to it?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-marketing-cloud

in SFMC, I am trying to convert a string datetime format

`2023-01-27T11:30:00.000+0000`

Expected : 15:30 (adding 4 hours to time) and displaying only time.

I tried various functions like

DateParse: %%=DateParse(@dateStr)=%%

StringToDate: %%=StringToDate(@dateStr)=%%

but this doesn't work.

expecting to display only time by adding 4 hours to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%[
    SET @dateStr = "2023-01-27T11:30:00.000+0000"
    SET @timeOnly = Format(DateAdd(@dateStr, 4, "H"), "HH:mm")
]%%

%%=v(@timeOnly)=%%
```

This will return "15:30"

The first line is setting the string to the variable @dateStr, so that this variable can be used in the next line of code.

The second line is using `DateAdd()` function with input of `@dateStr`, 4 as number of hours and "H" as the unit of hours. This will add 4 hours to the datetime.

Then, the `Format()` function is used with the DateAdd output as input, and "HH:mm" as format. This will format the datetime to only include the time in the format of hours and minutes. The output will be stored in the variable `@timeOnly`.

You can then use the variable @timeOnly to display it in your email or cloud page.